# Android - Passing JSON object from webview javascript to java

Tags: javascript, android, json, webview

I have an Activity with a webview and a javascript interface on the java side.I would like to write a method in Java that can accept a json paramater from the webview.

```
@JavascriptInterface
public String test(Object data) {
    Log.d("TEST", "data = " + data);
}
```

on my webview javascript I call:

```
MyAPI.test({ a: 1, b: 2 });
```

but the data variable is null.

How can I pass JSON objects from webview javascript into native method?

Thanks

Comment: You can only pass Strings and primitives.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) library or similar to create Stringified JSON to Java object, and `JSON.stringify(data)` on JS side

Answer (score 2):

@njzk2 is right, do it like this:

In JAVA:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public String test(String data) {
   Log.d("TEST", "data = " + data);
   return "this is just a test";
}
```

In JS:

```
// some code 
var result = test("{ a: 1, b: 2 }");
alert(result);
//some code

function test(args) {
   if (typeof Android != "undefined"){ // check the bridge 
      if (Android.test!= "undefined") { // check the method
         Android.test(args);
      }
   }
}
```